# Callback in vanilla JS function doesn't always work?

Tags: javascript, function, callback, xmlhttprequest

I've written a small vanilla JS function to utilise the XMLHttpRequest object. I have a callback to return, but for some reason I can only get the callback to work on the `onreadystatechange` function, I need it to work on my `ontimeout` and `onerror`...

My function:

```js
function makeHttpRequest (type, url, timeout, callback) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

  xhr.open(type, url, true)
  xhr.timeout = timeout
  xhr.ontimeout = () => {
    callback.apply('timeout error')
  }

  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.response != null) {
      callback.apply(xhr)
    }
  }

  xhr.onerror = () => {
    callback.apply('generic error')
  }

  xhr.send()
}
```

How I'm using the function:

```js
makeHttpRequest('GET', url, timeout, function() {
  const res = this.response != '' ? this.response : JSON.stringify({})
  // ...
})
```

`this.response` doesn't contain anything when used on timeout and error.

Comment: Well, depending on the error, there might be no response? What else do you expect?

Comment: You should not use `callback.apply`. Do you know how the `this`  keyword works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apply` method sets a function's `this` argument to its first parameter. When a timeout or error occurs you call apply like this:

```
callback.apply('timeout error');
```

Thus, the `this` value is a string. If you at the [documentation for javascript strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String), you will see that a `String` object does not have a `.response` property. That is why `'timeout error'.response` does not contain anything (it is `undefined`).

If you want `this.response` to contain the error message then don't pass a string as `this`. Instead pass it as `.response`:

```
let error = {
    response: 'timeout error'
}

callback.apply(error)
```

Or more simply:

```
callback.apply({ response: 'timeout error' })
```